# What is best way to feed ffmpeg in Android?

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg

I have compiled ffmpeg for Android for rtmp.
I want to feed ffmpeg by video and audio (2 channels) at the same time. I found a solution by just one input (only video in my case) pipe streaming (stdin).
I'm trying to use pure Java code.

I know that ffmpeg can comsume data from numbered (or may be named Pipe):

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:Number ...
```

Number == 0 it means stdin (i'm using it for video)
 But what is the way to create a pipe of another number?

I've tried `mkfifo MYFIFO` but the Android gives me `IOExcepion`

I've tried Filedescriptor but getFd() give an error too. Futhermore, it requires high-level API.

Is it possible to solve this problem?